# Listen to changes without caring about state in Flutter Bloc

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, bloc, flutter-bloc

I am currently learning how to use the Bloc state management library in Flutter, and I have a scenario where I would like to listen to an action performed (e.g. clicking a button) and react to that action in a child widget down the widget tree using a Cubit. From the documentation, it seems like the only way to rebuild child widgets is by storing a state object and reacting to changes in the state. However in my case, I don't need to store any state, I just want to know if an action has been done and react every single time it has been invoked.

Given this example below, I want `WidgetB` to rebuild whenever the button in `WidgetA` has been pressed, but I can't figure out how to construct my Cubit to allow that without storing some kind of state object.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

// What should the code be here if I don't want to store any state?
class WidgetACubit extends Cubit<void> {
  WidgetACubit({initialState}) : super(initialState);

  void doSomething() => emit(null);
}

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: BlocProvider(
          create: (_) => WidgetACubit(),
          child: WidgetA(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WidgetA extends StatelessWidget {
  WidgetA({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            BlocProvider.of<WidgetACubit>(context).doSomething();
            print("Something has been done");
            WidgetB.count++;
          },
          child: const Text("Press me to do something"),
        ),
        WidgetB(),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class WidgetB extends StatelessWidget {
  static int count = 0;

  WidgetB({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<WidgetACubit, void>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Text("I've been rebuilt $count times");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't add the code as a comment to my original answer because it's too long. The somewhat "correct"-ish way would be to not use bloc for this. You don't need a state management solution when you don't want to have any state. You can create a widget to achieve the behavior you desire.

```
class RebuildInvokerProvider extends InheritedWidget {
  const RebuildInvokerProvider({
    Key? key,
    required Widget child,
    required this.rebuild,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  static RebuildInvokerProvider of(BuildContext context) {
    final RebuildInvokerProvider? result =
        context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<RebuildInvokerProvider>();
    assert(result != null, 'No RebuildInvokerProvider found in context');
    return result!;
  }

  final void Function() rebuild;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(RebuildInvokerProvider oldWidget) {
    return oldWidget.rebuild != rebuild;
  }
}

class RebuildInvoker extends StatefulWidget {
  const RebuildInvoker({
    super.key,
    required this.child,
  });

  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<RebuildInvoker> createState() => _RebuildInvokerState();
}

class _RebuildInvokerState extends State<RebuildInvoker> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RebuildInvokerProvider(
      child: widget.child,
      rebuild: () => setState(() {}),
    );
  }
}
```

You can use a custom widget like this to achieve the behavior you desire. Wrap a widget with a RebuildInvoker, and when you want to rebuild that widget and all its children from within one of the children, call `RebuildInvokerProvider.of(context).rebuild()`. Not sure why you would want to do this though. I did not test the code by the way.

PS.
returning `oldWidget.rebuild != rebuild` from updateShouldNotify is not necessary for this to work and does not really have anything to do with how and why this works. This just causes widgets that depend on RebuildInvoker to also do a rebuild when the value of `rebuild` changes. But this value stays the same, in this particular example anyways. Just added this PS to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The BlocBuilder widget works by subscribing to the Cubit's state stream. So, you will not be able to rebuild your widget using a BlocBuilder while completely circumventing the usage of any state object. You could either just use a dummy state class without any methods and properties for your Cubit's state, and emit a new instance of that whenever you call cubit.doSomething. Or you can create a custom Widget for rebuilding which you use instead of BlocBuilder.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, is there a way to do this without this "hacky" workaround?

Comment: I'm not really sure why you would want to do what you are trying to, but the somewhat "correct"-ish way would be to not use bloc for this. You don't need a state management solution when you don't want to have any state. You can create a custom widget to achieve the behavior you desire.

Answer (score 0):

It is always emitting the same instance(`null`) that's why it wont rebuild. if you insist to rebuilt it like this, you can emit different value like

```dart
class WidgetACubit extends Cubit<void> {
  WidgetACubit({initialState}) : super(initialState);
  int count = 0;
  void doSomething() => emit(count++);
}
```

Btw I cannot get why do you need to use void cubit which can an event on bloc.

You can check the [flutter bloccore concepts](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/flutterbloccoreconcepts) for more.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the reason why I don't use events to store the state is that there is really only one event to store in this case, which is whether the button has been pressed. I am open to suggestions on how I can make this less "hacky" but I can't really see how to do this without storing a dummy state as you mentioned.

Comment: you can skip using bloc for this case, it can be done with `ValueNotifier` instead of using static variable. Also current hack will work,